# How to make a window as a container base window

Tags: wpf

I would like to make a window as a container base window for the other windows just like the SQL Management Studio main window
[image]

I remember it is a just property in the windows application project..How can i do this in WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [something like MDI](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: Yes,but is there any built-in function or property to do the same?